Visual Studio SSDT Publish fails
Using Visual Studio 2022 v17.10.1
Using a project with multiple SSDT databases, need to publish fairly frequently.
Most of the time it doesn't work: after clicking Publish, I set the publish properties, click the Publish button - and... - nothing happens.
What can I do?

I would assume that you haven't saved either the files or project/solution file. Get used to hit CTRL+SHIFT+S every time you want to publish. I would also assume you to rename the topic to something like: "... Publish is not publishing anything" or something like that as in your key the publish is not failing.

My CTRL, SHIFT and S buttons are worn by the frequent pressing :-)

These are the remedies that helped at least once

Close the output window / tab named "Data Tools Operations and re-try the publish
Close all open editor windows and re-try the publish
If you have multiple .publish.xml files in the data project you are trying to publish delete them and re-try the publish

